working engine temperature oil vs coolant
When we say that the car must be at working temperature, i.e. (90 C, 194F) is this temperature that of the coolant or the oil?
Thanks.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

The working temps of coolant should be around 100-110°C (212-230°F or maybe even a bit higher depending on how the engineers setup the engine) of most engines today. This website states oil should be about 115°C (240°F) on gasoline engines and 99°C (210°F) on diesel engines. While the 90°C temp you're talking about is close, I don't think it can be claimed it applies to either as a working temperature.
